# Add Data-validation to an entire column in exceljs

Tags: javascript, exceljs

How Do we add data-validation to an entire column in exceljs ?
Or Is there any other library that supports such a feature ?

Answer (score 5):

You can reach that by providing fixed number of cells in the target column, assuming the target column is column **L**, then you can use the following snippet:

```
sheet.dataValidations.add('L2:L9999', {
  type: 'list',
  allowBlank: false,
  formulae: ['"male,female,other"'],
  showErrorMessage: true,
  errorStyle: 'error',
  error: 'The value Valid',
});
```

For more info, see the following:
[how to set validation on a column #1109](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1109) &
[Data validation to the whole column? #614](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/614)